# Ternary operator in a while loop in C#

Tags: c#, while-loop, boolean, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

I'm very new to programming and I was wondering how could I break out the loop if the number is valid with a ternary operator? I'm used to do it with if-else but in this case I don't know the proper syntax to do it or if it is possible. 
Thanks!

```
while (!valid)
{
     .....
     Console.Write("Enter your phone number : ");
     string noTelephone = Console.ReadLine();
     string message = ValiderTelephone(noTelephone) ? "Numéro valide" : "Numéro invalide";
}
```

Comment: You can't, unless you use a `throw` expression (*don't*). If/else is the proper syntax for this.

Comment: Ternary operator is *operator* it returns some *value*, not changes control *flow*. Put `if` instead

Comment: You could do something like `valid=ValiderTelephone(noTelephone); string message = valid ? "Numéro valide" : "Numéro invalide";` that way the next loop will not execute because the while condition `!valid` will be false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go the way that Magnetron indicated in the comments if you're desperate for something that uses a ternary, but realistically there isn't any point in arranging the code lol you have/setting the message if you're going to loop until it's valid, because you don't use the message you set! This means that by the time the code reaches a point where message could be used for something, it must surely be "Number valid"

How about:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter number:");
string num = Console.ReadLine();
while(!ValidNumber(num)){
  Console.WriteLine("Invalid number, try again:");
  num = Console.ReadLine();
}
string message = "Number valid";
```

Or better:

```
private string Ask(string question){
  Console.WriteLine(question);
  return Console.ReadLine();
}

...

string num = Ask("Enter number:");
while(!ValidNumber(num))
  num = Ask("Invalid number, try again:");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I know there is better way to do it but I'm still learning and I want to try all the different tools I can so I can have a better understanding of what is more efficient and why. :)